# Help in computing $\int \frac{\vec{r}}{r-\vec{r}\vec{n}} d\vec{S}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Please help me integrate the function \begin{equation} \vec{v}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r-\vec{r}\vec{n}} \end{equation} on the surface of a sphere with radius R. $\vec{r}$ denotes a vector which is of the form \begin{equation}\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right)\end{equation} in rectangular coordinates. $r$ denotes the lenght of the same vector and $\vec{n}$ is an arbitrary unit vector. I can do most part (parametrizing the surface of the sphere, etc.), but I don't know what to do with the $\vec{r}\vec{n}$ term, since it leads to a numerator with sines and cosines in it, which is quite hard to integrate. However this should be a very simple exercise, but I just can't find the trick. Thank you in advance.

Update:
Parametrizing the surface of the sphere the usual way in spherical polar coordinates yields:

\begin{equation}\vec{s}(\theta, \phi) = R \left(\begin{matrix} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta\end{matrix}\right) \end{equation}

\begin{equation}d\vec{S} = \frac{\partial s}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial s}{\partial \phi} d\theta d \phi = R^2 \left(\begin{matrix} \sin^2 \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin^2 \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta \sin \theta \end{matrix} \right) d\theta d \phi \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \vec{v}(\vec{s}) d\vec{S} = \frac{R^3 \left(\begin{matrix} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} \sin^2 \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin^2 \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta \sin \theta \end{matrix} \right)}{R - R \left(\begin{matrix} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} n_1 \\ n_2 \\ n_3 \end{matrix}\right) } d\theta d\phi =  \frac{R^3 \sin \theta\,d\theta d\phi}{R - R \left(\begin{matrix} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} n_1 \\ n_2 \\ n_3 \end{matrix}\right)}\end{equation}

And now you can see the problem explicitly, since $\vec{n}$ is arbitrary, this leaves a very messy calculation, at least in this form. Any idea about how to compute the integral is welcome.

Comment: What is $\vec r\vec n$?  Clifford product?  Inner product?  Tensor product?

Comment: It denotes an inner product.

Comment: Why not show us what you've got so far?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip I've updated the question.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that there is a nice answer?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Yes, I do, because it's only a subexercise of a much greater one. However, 10 hours from now I will be writing a test on the subject, and at the and I'm going to ask the teacher about the solution, then I'm also going to post it here.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is an improper integral. At some point on the sphere $\vec{r}$ will be parallel to $\vec{n}$, so that $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n}=r$ and you are dividing by $0$. It's not clear to me that the integral converges.

Comment: Our comments crossed. I'll be interested in seeing the solution.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Yes, I can relate to that :D